# What does this Code in Assembler do?

Tags: assembly

I am given the following code and now try to understand it.

Array is poiting to a sufficient large memory, in .bss the code is preinitialized with 0.

```
1 fib : file format elf 32−i386
2
3 Disassembly of section.text :
4
5 0 x08048080 <start>:
6 0 x08048080 : mov eax , 0x80490d0 <array>
7 0 x08048085 : push eax
8 0 x08048086 : mov eax , 0 x3
9 0 x0804808b : push eax
10 0 x0804808c : call 0 x8048098 <fib>
11 0 x08048091 : pop eax
12 0 x08048092 : pop eax
13 0 x08048093 : jmp 0 x80480c1 <Lend>
14
15 0 x08048098 <fib>:
16 0 x08048098 : mov ebx , [esp+0x8]
17 0 x0804809c : mov ecx , 0 x2
18 0 x080480a1 : xor edx , edx
19 0 x080480a3 : mov [ebx] , edx
20 0 x080480a5 : mov eax , 0x1
21 0 x080480aa : mov [ebx+0x4] , eax
22 0 x080480ad : jmp 0 x080480ba <Lloop_cond>
23
24 0 x080480b2 <Lloop >:
25 0 x080480b2 : push eax
26 0 x080480b3 : add eax , edx
27 0 x080480b5 : mov [ebx+ecx∗4] , eax
28 0 x080480b8 : pop edx
29 0 x080480b9 : inc ecx
30
31 0 x080480ba <Lloop_cond>:
32 0 x080480ba : cmp ecx , [esp+0x4]
33 0 x080480be : jle 0x080480b2 <Lloop>
34 0 x080480c0 : ret
35
36 0 x080480c1 <Lend>:
37 0 x080480c1 : mov ebx , 0 x0 ; Exit code 0 = success
38 0 x080480c6 : mov eax , 0 x1 ; Select System call exit
39 0 x080480cb : int 0 x80 ; System call
40
41 Disassembly of section.bss :
42
43 0 x080490d0 <array>:
44 . . .
```

It demanded or neccessary I could provide my thoughts, however fear that it confuses more than it does good. 
Thanks for any constructive help.

Comment: I noticed this exact question was used as a [homework assignment](http://www3.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/Lehre/GRa/Klausuren/klausur-gra-2012-04-13.pdf) at a German University a few years back. Without your thoughts and your current understanding of the code or a specific question about something you don't understand - you appear at the moment asking us to do your homework.

Comment: @MichaelPetch It appears that this has been literally copied from the PDF you linked.

Comment: @MichaelPetch If you are so good at researching, then you also aware that there are currently holidays in Germany and there is no homework given during holidays, thus I ask because I want to know not because I need a good remark on a next homework. But whatever. Usually one does not get a useful comment on SO (not even talking about answers), however sometimes those comments are still good enough to do a reverse engineering and understand, how things work.

Comment: In your question you said **"It demanded or neccessary I could provide my thoughts,"** .I'm asking you to provide your thoughts.Edit your question, tell us what you have learned,what you think some of the code is doing, and if you have a specific question about the code you don't understand you can ask that.Whether on vacation or not isn't relevant. This an exact copy of an exam question/homework assignment from a few years ago I don't think it is particularly useful for students to ask others to do **all the work** for this kind of question, as it doesn't make the student think for themselves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is called `fib` and it is making an array of Fibonacci sequence. The body of the work is done at the few instructions following label `Lloop`.

```
Lloop:
    push eax                ; save current term
    add eax , edx           ; add previous term
    mov [ebx+ecx*4] , eax   ; write to array
    pop edx                 ; retrieve previous term for next loop
    inc ecx                 ; loop control and array index

Lloop_cond:
    cmp ecx , [esp+0x4]     ; end test
    jle Lloop               ; repeat
    ret                     ; done
```

I'll leave the rest of it to you.

Comment: Ah. a green tick quickly withdrawn and replaced by a downvote. How nice! I have answered the question at the top of the page, and annotated the essential part of the code.

Comment: This is SO, what did you expect? You won't get gratitude or a thank you here. But whatever. I thank you for your response. I use it, re-edit my question and mark with my comments my progress.

Comment: So why did you withdraw the green tick? Did you expect a complete reverse-engineer?

Comment: Do people here actually care? I didn't expect a full explanation of the code, that would be insane + kinda of rude. A "basic" idea or the purpose of the code, something you can write in 1 line of comment, had actually been enough.

Answer (score 2):

So the proper answer has already been given, and the reason for the question might be shady, but I need to work on my assembly as well and it was a fun exercise.

My reverse engineered fib boils down to this function:

```
void fib_simple(int* array, int n)
{
    int i, j, tmp;
    int count = 2;

    array[0] = i = 0;
    array[1] = j = 1;

    for (count = 2; count <= n; count++) {
        tmp = j;
        j = array[2] = i + j;
        i = tmp;
    }
}
```

Now of course it's only a concise transliteration. The actual reverse engineered function looks more like this:

```
void fib(int* array, int n)
{
    int ecx, edx, tmp;

    /* mov ebx , [esp+0x8]; ebx is the array */
    /* mov ecx , 0x2; ecx is a counter, starting from 2 */
    ecx = 2;

    /* xor edx, edx  ; set edx to zero     */
    edx = 0;

    /* mov [ebx], edx; set array[0] to edx */
    array[0] = edx;

    /* mov eax , 0x1 */
    eax = 1;

    /* mov [ebx+0x4] , eax */
    array[1] = 1;

    /* The while loop condition is checked with a loop condition:
    <Lloop_cond>:          ; place to jump back to every iteration
    cmp ecx , [esp+0x4]    ; compare to n
    jle 0x080480b2 <Lloop> ; if ecx <= n, jump to loop
    */
    while (ecx <= n) {
        /*
        This is the inner loop
        <Lloop >:
        */

        /* push eax; eax is temporarily saved to stack */
        tmp = eax;

        /* add eax, edx */
        eax += edx;

        /* mov [ebx+ecx∗4], eax */
        array[ecx] = eax;

        /* pop edx */
        edx = tmp;

        /* inc ecx */
        ecx++;
    }

    /* ret */
    return;
}
```

Comment: I like the question and worked it out more or less for myself since a proper answer has been given and OP understands the question. My post does more than provide thoughts and straight up solves the homework. (not exactly what is meant at SO)